# What is this yellow component in my Samsung mains charger and what is its purpose?

Tags: identification, components

What is this yellow component in my Samsung mains charger? On the top is written "DT0506C" and on the side is written "ETAOU81EBE BE 1218".

Similar looking components I've found were transformers. In my opinion it is way too far away from the rectifier and the mains connection. Its traces point me nearer to the USB port.

In the third picture is the bottom perspective with the component (yellow), mains connection (red), and probably rectifier (green).

[image: top]

[image: side]

[image: bottom]

Comment: It is a transformer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the transformer.

> But in my opinion its way too far away from the rectifier and the mains connection

That's because it's a switching supply. Mains is rectified first, resulting in about 320V DC in the two blue CrapXon caps, then this is chopped into a square wave, fed into the transformer, and rectified in the other side. The frequency is much higher than 50Hz mains, which allows a much smaller transformer and secondary smoothing caps, and lower weight and cost.

Here's a bit more detail about how a [flyback power supply](https://www.electronicdesign.com/power-management/power-supply/whitepaper/21808957/the-flyback-powersupply-architecture-and-operation) works.

Comment: To be fair, I've seen lots of devices with capXon's that never had a problem when correctly designed. Its more about some penny pinching by using lower product range or not enough capacitors and exceeding their ratings.